# Получить массив обьектов из Json в Angular 4

Tags: angular2

Не могу получить массив обьектов при получении Json обьектов в Angular

Код cервиса:

```
   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Post } from './Post';


@Injectable()
export class BlogPostsService {

  posts: any[];
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getAllPosts()
  {
   this.http.get('http://localhost:63223/api/Post/Posts').subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
return this.posts;

  }

}
```

тут я получаю и вывожу в консоль json обьекты: http://prntscr.com/ha8545

но когда я хочу записать json в переменную для использования ее потом в выводе html то пишет http://prntscr.com/ha862p

код с переменной:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Post } from './Post';


@Injectable()
export class BlogPostsService {

  posts: any[];
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getAllPosts()
  {
   this.http.get('http://localhost:63223/api/Post/Posts').subscribe((data: any[]) => this.posts = data);
return this.posts;

  }

}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий вариант. Код сервиса

```
 getAllPosts(): Observable<Post[]> {
   return this.http.get('assets/file.json')
     .map( (data) => {
        let postList = [].slice.call(data);
        return postList.map(function(post: any){
          return {
            id: post.id,
            userName: post.userName,
            postName: post.postName,
            postText: post.postText,
            createdPost: post.createdPost
      }
    })
  });
}
```

Соответственнно параметр строку get меняете под свой url.  Дальше в основном компоненте прописываете

```
  postList: Post[] = [];

  constructor(private someService: SomeService) {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
     this.someService.getAllPosts()
           .subscribe((data) => {this.postList = data;});
  }
```

Плюс ко всему я создал класс Post, исходя из вашего json файла для хранения

```
export class Post {
  id: number;
  userName: string;
  postName: string;
  postText: string;
  createdPost: string
}
```

Comment: Web Api  контроллер отправляет данные на запрос но я получаю  http://prntscr.com/hab2yw

Comment: вы точно указали путь к json?

Comment: Да. Я проверял. Контроллер отдает массив.

Comment: ключи json должны совпадать с ключами класса Post

Comment: Вы поля имеете ввиду?

Comment: Да 
[
    {
      "id": "1",
      "userName":"Mitch",
      "postName": "somepost name",
      "postText": "sometext name",
      "createdPost": "21.01.2012"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "userName":"Mitch",
      "postName": "somepost name",
      "postText": "sometext name",
      "createdPost": "21.01.2012"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "userName":"Mitch",
      "postName": "somepost name",
      "postText": "sometext name",
      "createdPost": "21.01.2012"
    }
  ]

Comment: Пример выше написал и проверил у себя

Comment: поля я скопировал из вьюшной модели со стороны сервера

Comment: http://prntscr.com/hab6if

Comment: Хорошо. Еще поработаю. Можно еще один вопрос

Comment: @РоманПетров Давайте

Comment: На контроллер не приходят данные http://prntscr.com/hab8h5

Comment: метод get() вы использовали в прошлый раз

Comment: Пробовал через Postman отправлять...все приходит.

Comment: Да. Сечас мне нужно отправиить данные для регистрации...но ничего не приходит